# Iphone - Overlay text on GIF with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animated-gif

How do i add Text on GIF or on UIImage with contain of `animationImages` array

This is how I animated the GIF:

```
self.imageView.animationImages = NSArray(array: (AppInstance?.arrGIFPHotos)!) as? [UIImage]
```

need to Add text on this Imageview.

Comment: Like text that matches the gif frame? or just like a static label that appears over the image

Comment: need a label over the frame and end result should be merge that label and gif.

Answer (score 1):

I would just add a UILabel above the gif.